# WSL loses connection in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I develop a project using WSL in VSCode with [Remote WSL extention](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl). It works fine until I try to build (with hot reload) the front end of the project with parcel-bundler. In the VSCode I get a message "Cannot reconnect. Please reload the window". Once I reload the window, I don't get any errors and the project is re-built successfully each time I make any changes. But when I rerun the command to build the project it happens again.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4686 (not sure. could be a different issue with similar symptoms)